# How to fix broken toilet flange from over tightened bolt?

Tags: bathroom, toilet, drain-waste-vent, pvc, flange

I broke my PVC toilet flange when I over-tightened the bolt used to secure the toilet to the flange.  How do I fix this without replacing the entire PVC fitting? This PVC flange is glued to the drain pipe so I can't just pull out the fitting to replace it.

Here is what it looks like, the red circle shows where the bolt was that snapped the flange.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can purchase a toilet flange repair at any big box hardware store.

Remove the wax ring (buy a new one), remove the bolts, and mount this on top of the existing broken flange:
[image]

Then reattach the toilet as per normal, making sure not to over tighten.

Tip, seat the toilet firmly on the wax ring before you tighten the bolts, and use a STANDARD sized wax ring not a jumbo - if the toilet starts out firmly on the floor before you start tightening then you know you're tight enough when the washer starts to bend in just a little.

Answer (score 1):

You may also be able to get toilet bolts that screw into the wood. That is, if you have a wood floor under the flange.

Answer (score 0):

I drilled down through the floor and installed carriage bolts through the floor with nuts on them.